# Virtual templated member function

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance, type-erasure

I know that one can not have a virtual templated member function but I want something working similar to it.

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
struct abstract
{
    template<typename T>
    virtual T get() const = 0;
};

using abstract_pointer = std::shared_ptr<abstract>;

struct concrete_int : public abstract
{
    template<>
    int get() const { return 123; }
};

struct concrete_string : public abstract
{
    template<>
    std::string get() const { return "abc"; }
};

abstract_pointer factory()
{
    // Some logic here to decide what concrete type to return
    return ...;
}

void print_value(abstract_pointer p)
{
    // Will print either 123 or "abc"
    std::cout << "p = " << p->get() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    abstract_pointer p = factory();

    print_value(p);
}
```

The main code will only use the `abstract_pointer` type, it should not really know anything about the concrete classes.

It could easily be solved with CRTP and type deduction, but then it's not really possible to pass the object around to other function like in the example above.

I could also be using Boost variant, or unions, but then it could quickly become unwieldy if more concrete classes are added. I could also use Boost any, but then I would have to use `any_cast` and it would not be so... well, *nice* and simple.

It might just be that my google-fu is bad today, or I'm just too tired, but I haven't really found any way around it. Is it possible to do something like this while still keeping it flexible enough to add more concrete classes, and also keeping the interface simple and nice?

---

A little explanation about the use case: This is to be a part of a small lexical analyzer for a simple compiler I'm making (just for fun though), and the abstract class in the example above is the "token" class, and the concrete classes are specific tokens like "integer token" or "string token" or "identifier token".

The reason I want to use abstract/concrete classes and inheritance is because I want to make the lexer flexible enough to be used by multiple languages, so it should be easy to, for example, add a "identifier token" child class for "keyword token", and maybe even one concrete class for each keyword.

But maybe AaronI is correct that I try to hard to make something complex. I'll let this question stand in case someone comes up with a good solution, or finds a good duplicate, meanwhile I'll think more about it and see if I can come up with something acceptable myself.

Comment: Whenever I needed such I resorted to CRTP. However even CRTP allows to have abstract (non templated) base classes, to make it easier to pass these around. I have used this approach heavily with my [STTCL state machine framework](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl).

Comment: Maybe check Boost.TypeErasure?

Comment: can't the abstract object simply support visiting? It's difficult to understand the requirement without knowing the use case.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying too hard to use complex template-fu when there is no need for it. If what you want is the ability to print something, it would be much easier to just have a print method on your object and override it as necessary, or alternatively to have a to_string method.

Comment: @AaronI It's not just for printing. Updated my question with the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct abstract
{
    virtual string get() const = 0;
};

using abstract_pointer = std::shared_ptr<abstract>;

struct concrete_int : public abstract
{
    string get() const override { return "123"; }
};

struct concrete_string : public abstract
{
    string get() const override { return "abc"; }
};

abstract_pointer factory()
{
    // Some logic here to decide what concrete type to return
    return ...;
}

void print_value(abstract_pointer p)
{
    // Will print either 123 or "abc"
    std::cout << "p = " << p->get() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    abstract_pointer p = factory();

    print_value(p);
}
```

Easy-peasy. :)

Disclaimer: code not reviewed by compiler.

Comment: Shouldn't `get()` in `concrete_int` return an `int` instead of a `string`?

Comment: Easy-peasy indeed, but not *quite* what I was looking for... :) I'll keep it in mind as an alternative through, we'll see how it turns out in the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to introduce new keywords as tokens and at the same time use generic smart pointer to access all the tokens then, it somewhat becomes necessary that 'token::get()' returns something which is fundamental enough to be understood by the code which calls 'token::get()'. Consider 'token' here as an abstract class.

If you are printing (using 'cout') the token via 'get()' and if some concrete token returns an object then 'cout' won't understand what that object is or how to print the object.

In such case converting all the tokens to some common fundamental type (say, 'char*' or 'string' as suggested by "Cheers and hth. - Alf") seems good.

Also, if printing is one of the requirement then, following function can be added to the abstract class:

```
virtual void token::print(ostream &);
```

In this way every concrete object will print itself.